# Proper way to use the Windows Forms Designer on a project created with the .NET CLI?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am working on a C# project with the general workflow of editing in whatever we want (I use VS Code personally) and building with the .NET SDK via the CLI.  However, I need to create some Windows Forms for a piece of the project and would like to use the Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer to edit the forms graphically, but I am struggling to figure out how to do so because the project was not created in Visual Studio.

If I open the .csproj file via File > Open > Project/Solution in Visual Studio and then double click my form, the designer fails to launch, giving me a pop up error with a link to install .NET Core 3.0 (even though this is a .NET 8.0 project) and I get the following console output from Windows Forms:

```
: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\'.
: Failed to run as a self-contained app.
:   - The application was run as a self-contained app because '\\?\C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_f971214a\WinFormsDesigner\ycjrcxah.b4c\DesignToolsServer.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
:   - If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in '\\?\C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_f971214a\WinFormsDesigner\ycjrcxah.b4c\DesignToolsServer.runtimeconfig.json'.
```

I know my .csproj is set up correctly with the right framework as it builds fine from the CLI SDK.  In fact, the problem can be reproduced from a basic autogenerated dotnet template:

#### Minimal Working Example:

1. Run `dotnet new winforms`
2. Open the generated .csproj file in Visual Studio
3. Double click `Form1.cs` in the solution explorer

Comment: You might try creating a WinForms project with `dotnet new` and then creating one with VS and comparing the results

Comment: I could not reproduce with the given steps. Works fine for me. VS 2022 17.8p1. You might want to try out in the `Preview Features` under Settings: `Use the preview Windows Forms out-of-process designer for .NET apps (requires restart)

Comment: @Hank well that particular option wasn't the problem but while looking there I noticed preview SDKs weren't enabled and this is a .NET8.0 project.  Enabling that option and restarting VS fixed the issue.  What an obtuse error behavior for such a simple thing as not having the right SDK version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apparently, this error is an indication that the correct SDK is not installed (or enabled) in Visual Studio**.

There seems to be no catch to recognize the lack of the right SDK and it instead falls back on failing to find specific SDK files.

In my case, the culprit was the project in question was using the .NET 8.0 preview and preview SDKs were not enabled under *Tools > Manage Preview Features > **Use Previews of the .NET SDK***.

Comment: Your answer is helpful! You can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT FYI you're not allowed accept mark self-posted answers for 2 days.